# Make 2 column and the first column is span in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know what suitable title for this question.

How to make column in Bootstrap 3 like this [picture](https://i.postimg.cc/JzkNTR5r/Screenshot-153.jpg)?

So the second column height is always same as first column, and height div inside second column is equal each others.

If you have a similiar question, tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please refer this => http://jsfiddle.net/L9zdmr7t/
I have made a basic markup for the design which you have given. Check this in  your laptop/Desktop

Comment: @king thanks for your code. I want the second column height same as first and second child div height is equal 50% 50%. Please see my pic https://i.postimg.cc/hGHjs3qN/Screenshot-154.jpg

Answer (score 0):

By default, Bootstrap columns are left floating so if placed within a row you can force the height of your first column to accommodate for any other columns that may fit to its right. This should accomplish the layout you are looking for: https://www.bootply.com/vDgyXDwB4g

Comment: There is no way from the second column height follow the first and height div inside second column is equal 50% 50% like this (i.postimg.cc/hGHjs3qN/Screenshot-154.jpg)?